# Heroku logs show syntax error in syck.rb. How to resolve this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 3.2 app to Heroku.

When I migrate the database, the rake is aborted.

Checking the logs I see

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 7, col 11: `' (ArgumentError)
```

I've tried to track down what's causing this, including disabling all non essential gems, reviewing the app for obvious syntax errors, etc. But no luck.

As this error seems to be generated by a Heroku system file, I'm not sure what to try next.

Has anyone else encountered this? Are there any good references that would help me get to the bottom of this?

Comment: sounds like a syntax error on line 7 of a yml file somewhere. I assume  everything is ok locally, so either that yml file has contents based on environment variables or the difference comes from using psych (the new yaml parser) locally but syck on heroku

Comment: thanks @frederick. this had been driving me crazy for over a week! My app uses Koala. In facebook.yml I had not included app details (app ID, etc) for all environments. Once I added this info, everything worked fine! Thanks again. Would you like to add this as an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a syntax error on line 7 of a yml file somewhere.

I assume everything is ok locally, so either that yml file has contents based on environment variables which differ between development and production (and the values in production result in incorrect yaml) or the difference comes from using psych (the new yaml parser) locally but syck on heroku. You can check which parser is being used with YAML::ENGINE.

Comment: Just as a side note, I received this error in Sinatra and it was due to the last line for my "password" field not have a carriage return. YAML is a format reliant on spacing and newlines, so be careful with whitespace etc.